# Cross-domain AJAX request to the WCF

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf, cross-domain

I have a hard Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, I want to make cross domain query from your web service to a WCF service, but it does not work.

Ajax code on a web page:

```
$.ajax (
    url: "http:/сите.com/ApplicationController.svc/HelloPost/"
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert (data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert (jqXHR textStatus errorThrown);<br/>
    }
});
```

But my WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke (Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "HelloPost /", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
[JSONPBehavior (callback = "callback")]
String GetPostHello (Stream data);

public String GetPostHello (Stream data)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader ("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader ("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End ();
        return null;
    }
    return "Hello";
}
```

When a GET request with the domain it works, but try to make a POST request returns this header:

`Content-Type application/json
Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*;q=0.01`

**Help, what could be the problem! Thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

For POST requests to be made cross-domain by browsers which support CORS (which is what you're using with the *Access-Control* headers), prior to the request the browser first sends a *preflight* request, which is a HTTP `OPTIONS` request, asking the server whether is ok to send the POST request to it. You can either add another operation which responds to the OPTIONS request, or you can implement full CORS support for WCF - it's not too simple, but I've wrote about it on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/05/15/implementing-cors-support-in-wcf.aspx with the steps required to make this work.

Comment: Your example is unfortunately not run in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.
message:
The selected file is a solution file, but was created by a newer version of this application and cannot be opened.

Is it possible to create such an application in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: You should be able to create a new solution in VS2008 with the same projects as the one I have, then add the files as in the original project.